# OrientDB: Accessing query result data in Server side function

Tags: javascript, orientdb

OrientDB allowes to create server side javascript functions.
Is there any way to access intermediate query results inside server side javascript function. Eg. If I return query results, I get json response array as expected. But if I try to access query result inbetween function like:

```
var comps = db.query("SELECT code from Company");

db.begin();
for(var i=0; i<comps.length; i++){
  var c = comps[i];
  db.save({
    "@class":"Temp",
    col:  c.code
  });
}
db.commit();

return comps;
```

For above function I get blank values stored in column "col".

As per my observation, OrientDb returns context instead of actual results inside the function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `c.code` with `c.field("code")`.

Comment: Does accessing fields in query results with field(name) work in javascript functions for OrientDB 2.x ? I can't get it to work. I get null values instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your remark "OrientDb returns context instead of actual results inside the function" I assume you are working with Java 8. The point is, behavior of OrientDB differs between Java 8 and Java 7 in this respect (because of the different underlying Javascript engines: Nashorn vs Rhino). There are several known (related) issues, see [this thread](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3051) for example.